# MariaDB on MacOS: where is the default ibdata1 file?

Tags: macos, mariadb

Using Homebrew, I install MariaDB. It installs fine, but where is the ibdata1 file stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/usr/local/var/mysql is the default data directory for MariaDB.

It includes the ibdata1 file, log files, etc

Answer (score 3):

On M1 Mac, Homebrew installs files into the /opt/homebrew/ folder.
So with MySQL/MariaDB installed by Homebrew, default data directory is /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/.

It contains all databases and ibdata1 and other files previously placed in /usr/local/var/mysql/.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

From your MySQL Command Prompt, after root login,

SELECT @@datadir;     should reveal the folder name